# Putting Together A Mailing List

Tags: groups, smartgroups

I want to put together a mailing list of all primary individual members (current, lapsed, expired) who have no email address.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Search Builder (under the Search menu).  On the first Search line, search for

> Contacts > Email > Primary > Is Empty

On the next search line(s), set your criteria for the members piece.

EDIT: And then you can save as a Smart Group which you can use as your List